# Manually Created Angular Component Not Showing Up

Tags: angular, typescript, import, angular-components

I just started learning Angular and am trying am practicing how to create a component using not only the CLI but manually as well. I created my component in a folder along with an HTML, CSS and .TS files. Here is my code below:

HTML & CSS

```
    <h1>WARNING ALERT: IT IS RAINING OUTSIDE!!</h1> //in HTML file
    h1
    {
      color:red; //in CSS file
    }
```

.TS file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-warning',
        templateUrl: 'src/app/warningalert/warningalert.component.html'
    })
    
    export class WarningAlertComponent{
    
    }
```

I added the element in the ***app.component.html*** like so:  `<app-warning></app-warning>` and imported it in the ***app.module.ts*** file like so:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {WarningAlertComponent} from 'src/app/warningalert/warningalert.component'; //Warning Component

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WarningAlertComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Everything else in my app.component.html file shows up except this newly created component and I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm missing. I read some SO posts and I imported component like they said but I still can't figure out why the component isn't showing up. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: ./src/app/warningalert/warningalert.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/app/warningalert/warningalert.component.html' in '/Users/Desktop/basics-assignment-1-start/src/app/warningalert'
```

Comment: How are you "manually" compiling it if you aren't using the CLI?

Comment: Also, are you generating your components using the CLI? If not, that will save you oceans of time and headache. https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/cli/creating-components

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your templateUrl to a relative path:

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-warning',
        templateUrl: './warningalert.component.html'
    })
```

Comment: I tried that as well but I got an error saying 'Cannot find module './warningalert.component.html' or its corresponding type declarations. ' @robbieAreBest

Comment: I'd try updating the import path in AppModule as well.  These errors are due to import issues.

Comment: Have you added css and spec.ts file properly?

Comment: I created the html, css, .ts and spec.ts files myself, currently the .ts file does not contain anything. It's weird because the error I'm getting in within the new components HTML file but there is no red underline anywhere. @KartikDolas